# Crystal - How to dynamically get global variables from modules in multiple files

Tags: crystal-lang

I have multiple files in this format:
car1.cr

```
module Cars
  module Car1
    BRAND = "TOYOTA"
  end
end
```

All of these files are getting required by a main file where I can do this:

```
puts Cars::Car1::BRAND #=> TOYOTA
```

What I'm trying to do is `puts` all brands of all files dynamically, allowing me to just create a new file (or delete a file) in the first format and automatically being able to get printed without adding it manually (or removing it) .

I tried following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531198/13508702 but couldn't manage to achieve my goal.

Any help would be apreaciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need the constants? Couldn't your files just build up a hash?

```
# cars.cr
module Cars
  BRANDS = {} of String, String
end

# car1.cr
module Cars
  module Car1
    BRANDS["Car1"] = "TOYOTA"

    # Or if you really need the constant
    BRAND = "TOYOTA"
    BRANDS["Car1"] = BRAND
  end
end

# Or if it really just defines the data
Cars::BRANDS["Car1"] = "TOYOTA"
```

I suspect you collect more info than the brand, so you may just define a value type:

```
module Cars
  record Car, name : String, brand : String, model : String

  CARS = [] of Car
end

Cars::CARS << Car.new("Car1", "TOYOTA", "AA")
```

The general answer here is, try to think of a way to restructure your program so that you don't need this meta-programming ability. That usually leads to cleaner and easier to follow code.

To answer the actual question:

```
module Cars
  module Car1
    BRAND = "TOYOTA"
  end

  module Car2
    BRAND = "HONDA"
  end

  def self.collect_brands
    {{@type.constants.map {|car| "#{car}::BRAND".id }}}
  end
end

Cars.collect_brands # => ["TOYOTA", "HONDA"]
```

Comment: This is far better than what I had in mind! Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In case helpful, I don't know if you can have an Array of module but an array of instances!

```
module Car
  abstract def brand : String
end

BRANDS = [] of Car

module Cars
  class Car1
    include Car
    def brand : String
      "TOYOTA"
    end
  end
end

BRANDS << Cars::Car1.new
```